# SQL Delete using another tables values

Tags: sql

I have three tables `Team` and `User_Has_Team` and `User`

In now i wish to delete the entity in `User_Has_Team` Where the `Username` is equal to `User_id` 1.

How would you go around this?

Comment: If you are trying to represent that a Team has many Users, and Users have many teams, then the naming convention of your join talbe should be `Teams_Users`.  If the relationship is not `many-to-many` then you don't need a third table, and you can represent the relationship using `FOREIGN KEYS` in your User table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM User_Has_Team WHERE users_id=1
```

If you wanted to delete a record given the username, a little more difficult

```
DELETE FROM User_Has_Team AS uht INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.id=uht.users_id WHERE u.name="Bob";
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to work: DELETE FROM User_has_Team uht INNER JOIN User u ON u.id=uht.User_id WHERE u.name= ?  AND uht.Team_id = ?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen.  Wasn't me who voted down.  Your query should work.  What isn't working?  Try doing a `SELECT` to see the User_ids and names that are being returned so you can make sure your WHERE clause is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The "ugly" way:

```
delete from user_has_team 
where username in (select username from user where id=1);
```

The "pretty" way is the answer by user1032531